# Governor Droop Response (Demand Balancing)

Tags: frequency, generator, transmission-line, power-generation

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve the governor droop response question in a textbook I am studying for a certification.

This is the question:

> A 100 MW generator at 50 MW output that has 5% governor droop response will respond how much to a -.15 HZ frequency deviation (Actual frequency = 59.85 HZ)?
>
> A) -10 MW
> B) -5 MW
> C) +5 MW
> D)  +10 MW

I do know that because the frequency deviation is below zero, that the governor droop response will be greater than zero, thus eliminating choices A and B. I looked at the answer pool in the back of the book and the answer is C.

I did this to see if I could figure out the problem by working backwards, but I cant seem to wrap my head around it. I am not an Electrical Engineering student, and I have been out of school for some time now.

How would I approach this kind of question, and is there any base formula I could use to solve for the droop response?

Comment: sorry to bother, what is the book you are studying?, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in speed from reference is:

$$ -0.15 \mathrm{Hz} \div 60 \mathrm{Hz} = 0.25\% $$

Out of the full 5% range of speed adjustment, this will be:

$$ 0.25\% \div 5\% = 5\% $$

Then, multiply for the result:

$$ 5\% \times 100 \mathrm{MW}= 5 \mathrm{MW}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it.